# Does Windows ever stop services when resuming from sleep?

Tags: windows, windows-8, sleep, services, windows-services

I'm running on windows 8.
Occasionally, when I resume from sleep, my service gets a stop request through the *SCM* (call to `SvcCtrlHandler` with `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP`). I wasn't able to trace the source of this request. Can it possibly be sent by the OS itself, in some scenario?

My two main suspicions right now:

1. If the resume event (`SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT` of type `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC`) is taking too long, the OS might stop the service (system logs contain logs referring to this specific service: `A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the [...] The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`)
2. The OS stops the service because it has been flagged as a problematic service (system logs contain logs referring to this specific service: `service did not shut down properly after receiving a preshutdown control`